# mysql query performance drop when using 'in' with multiple value

Tags: mysql

I have a query joining a table with many millions (tableA) rows with another with just 7000 rows (tableB). The query search in tableA the rows that are between a to and from date from tableB.
I have a where on tableB on the id to limit it to a set of ids.
When I use where tableB.id in ('1234')
it returns in a few seconds.
Same thing for where tableB.id in ('3456')
But if I use where tableB.id in ('1234', '3456') then it runs forever.

You can see the 2 explains are very different.

Why is it switching from a index range scan to an non-unique key lookup just because I have 1 or 2 ids from the other table ?

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM tableA t
join tableC b on t.tableC_id = b.id
join tableB tr on t.bassin_id = tr.bassinid
where  t.date between tr.date_entree and tr.date_sortie_reelle
and tr.id in ( '1234', '4567')
```

[image: explain pour 2 id]

[image: explain pour 1 id]

Comment: Show your table definition.

Comment: What is the `COUNT(*)` for just 1234?  And for the other value?  It sounds like the IN with 2 values is returning a _much_ larger count, hence it will take a _much_ longer time?

Comment: the IN is on the primary key. So the count is the number of entry in the "IN" clause.

Answer (score 0):

When you have IN ('1234') is like = 1234. The scan type is 'const'.

> The table has at most one matching row, which is read at the start of
> the query. Because there is only one row, values from the column in
> this row can be regarded as constants by the rest of the optimizer.
> const tables are very fast because they are read only once.
>
> const is used when you compare all parts of a PRIMARY KEY or UNIQUE
> index to constant values

When you have IN ('1234', '4567') it uses 'range'

> Only rows that are in a given range are retrieved, using an index to
> select the rows. The key column in the output row indicates which
> index is used. The key_len contains the longest key part that was
> used. The ref column is NULL for this type.
>
> range can be used when a key column is compared to a constant using
> any of the =, <>, >, >=, <, <=, IS NULL, <=>, BETWEEN, LIKE, or IN()
> operators:

Read more here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/explain-output.html#explain-join-types

P.S.: I hope you have indexes on the columns you use on ON and WHERE clauses. I have tested the performance on 2 tables with similar number of rows like you specified (all indexes set), using LEFT JOINS, SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE, and is pretty fast in both cases, under 1 sec on an i7 8700k with 32 GB DDR3 and nVME SSD.

Comment: I know that. What I want to know is why it changes strategy on the tableA (t on the explain diagram). Why can't it do an INDEX RANGE SCAN when there is 2 or more rows coming from tableB ?